# Error while executing php script

Tags: php

I am working on a blog app built using php.

I have a functionality that in case there are no blog entries, then user shall see a link from where he can be directed to blog entry page(new.php in my project).
I am able to show the link successfully, but I have a small issue:

my directory structure is 
blog->(index.php new.php)

when I am making the anchor tag refer to the new.php as

```
$e = array(
        'title'=> 'No entries yet',
        'entry'=> '<a href=" blog/new.php">Post an entry here!</a>'
        );
```

In this case when I click `<a>` tag, the browser address bar shows address as ***localhost:8080/blog/blog/new.php***

and if the change this to

```
$e = array(
        'title'=> 'No entries yet',
        'entry'=> '<a href="new.php">Post an entry here!</a>'
        );
```

then the address bar shows: ***localhost:8080/new.php***

In both cases, I am not able to show the page.

Comment: Use absolute paths: `"/blog/new.php"`.

Comment: And are you testing the site on localhost at port 8080 ? What should the address be?

Comment: solved it guys :) Thanks to mello.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$e = array(
    'title'=> 'No entries yet',
    'entry'=> '<a href="../blog/new.php">Post an entry here!</a>'
);
```

But is still better that you use absolute paths. It is a little better for performance. try to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, something like this:

```
$e = array(
    'title'=> 'No entries yet',
    'entry'=> '<a href="http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog/new.php">Post an entry here!</a>'
);
```